# How many chemical species are on average in a typical plant and animal cell?

Tags: cell-biology

I want to know what sort of range there is on the number of different chemical species in a typical plant and animal cell. Failing that, some specific examples (with sources please).

Thanks

Comment: What is a chemical for you?

Comment: anything that can diffuse in the cell

Comment: well there are about 6000 distinct proteins in a yeast cell. So I would guess in the hundreds of thousands. https://www.sciencealert.com/simple-cell-has-42-million-protein-molecules-life-universe-everything

Answer (score 0):

There is no average plant cell.  However this article describes a [whole plant flux balance model with 333 metabolites](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3793045/). This won't describe a lot of the molecules plants make.

I seem to remember a natural product analysis of garlic that had scores of sulphur containing compounds that give its distinctive smell for instance.  This model would be a simplified plant which has no special characteristics like that, which probably doesn't exist.  Its probably not less than half the number of compounds that some plants produce or use.